# Mask does not work when capturing a uiview to a uiimage

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, calayer, mask

I have a `UIView` which I want to save as a `UIImage`. I do this using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, and it works OK. But when I apply mask to the images in the (view/layer.mask), the image that I capture through `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` is wrong (the masking is working when running the app but not when trying to get a `UIImage` from a `UIView`). Anyone encountered similar problem?

Comment: Can you please provide some code showing what you have so far?

Comment: Are you masking the source UIView in advance of capturing the UIImage from it? or are you masking the resulting UIImage at the moment you're trying to display it in a UIImageView?

Comment: I added some example code.

Comment: There's no example code

Comment: Code for masking:

`UIImage *_maskingImage = self.maskImage;
CALayer *_maskingLayer = [CALayer layer];
_maskingLayer.frame = self.bounds;
[_maskingLayer setContents:(id)[_maskingImage CGImage]];
[self.layer setMask:_maskingLayer];`

Comment: Code for exporting UIView to UIImage:
`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, -x, -y);
[self.scrollView.layer renderInContext:c];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`

Comment: Wait. You're masking `self.layer`, but exporting `self.scrollView.layer`. Is it correct?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you wish to create a UIImage from a UIView layer, while that layer is masked. I assume that you want the target UIImage to have transparent background.

I encountered no problems implementing this and I have a demo project you can take a look at:

https://bitbucket.org/reydan/so_imagemask

You first need to press the **Mask** button. It will load a mask image (black and white) from the bundle and set it as the layer mask for the UIView container above.

Then, you can press the **Copy Image** button which renders the UIView container into an UIImage, and then  set it to the destination image view below to see the result.

I will also post the 2 methods here:

```
- (IBAction)onMask:(id)sender {

    UIImage* maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
    UIImageView* maskImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:maskImage];
    maskImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    maskImageView.frame = _mainContainerView.bounds;

    _mainContainerView.layer.mask = maskImageView.layer;
}

- (IBAction)onCopyImage:(id)sender {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_mainContainerView.bounds.size, FALSE, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [_mainContainerView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    _destImageView.image = img;
}
```

**EDIT**

Apparently `renderInContext:` on IOS6 does not use the mask (as it is also said here on SO).
My solution was to manually apply mask to the image. The mask is taken from the mask property of the layer and rendered in a context too so we don't have any problems with transformations/contentModes/etc.

Here is the updated source code (it is also available on bitbucket):

```
- (IBAction)onCopyImage:(id)sender {

    // Get the image from the mainImageView
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_mainContainerView.bounds.size, FALSE, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [_mainContainerView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    // Use the next block if targeting IOS6
    {
        // Manually create a mask image (taken from the mask layer)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_mainContainerView.bounds.size, TRUE, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, _mainContainerView.bounds);

        [_mainContainerView.layer.mask renderInContext:ctx];
        UIImage * maskimg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


        // Create a image mask from the UIImage
        CGImageRef maskRef = maskimg.CGImage;
        CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                            CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                            CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                            CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                            CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                            CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

        // Apply the mask to our source image
        CGImageRef maskedimg= CGImageCreateWithMask(img.CGImage, mask);

        // Convert to UIImage so we can easily display it in a UIImageView
        img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedimg scale:img.scale orientation:img.imageOrientation];

        CGImageRelease(mask);
        CGImageRelease(maskedimg);
    }



    _destImageView.image = img;

}
```

**EDIT**
Please check the latest project on bitbucket as it contains the latest version.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get squared UIView's in the UIImage. I use exactly the same code as you. I do not understand??? Your example project working for me. Can it be something with iOS 7 SDK. Your project is build in iOS 7 and mine for iOS 6. Can that make any different?

Comment: I will try and use ios 6 and come back with an answer

Comment: Indeed, it does not work on ios 6.1 I did not expect this. I will how I can update the project to make it work.

Comment: I added a new solution which uses a bit less memory but the mask images are inverted (because of how `CGImageCreateWithMask` works). It is also available on bitbucket.

Comment: Sorry but, in my project I have more than one masked UIView. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Of course. I updated the bitbucket project. I created a method which you can call for any UIView you wish to get the image from. It is independent and does not use any variables outside that method. You can even create a UIView category with this method to be able to access it easier.

Comment: I get a UIImage with the size 0x0. Any idea what it can depends on?

Comment: I have no idea. DO you do anything different than my sample project?

Comment: Now I got the mask for the hole UIImage and not the subviews. How can I set the position and size for the mask?

Comment: I believe that is another matter, a little beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: What I mean is that the mask takes up the hole UIImage and not just where the UIView is located. The green square is where the image should be. [link]http://s8.postimg.org/haqsce03l/Sk_rmavbild_2013_07_19_kl_20_10_17.png

Comment: Does the combination UIView + mask appear correctly on the screen? (before you try to capture it into a UIImageView). Can you please post a screenshot of that? Thanks

Comment: Heres a screenshot how the UIView looks like. The subview has a pattern background color. [link]http://s7.postimg.org/sfm1oi917/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_shot_19_jul_2013_21_12_05.png

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code which I have been used to get the UIView as UIImageView and Applying mask image for that .

```
 * UIView --> UIImageView --> With Mask images .
```

I have been used a UIView for the purpose of Drawing So for that ,

**Assigning the UIView(drawn area) into UIImageView .**

```
-(UIImage*) imageRepresentation
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    UIImageView* upsideDownImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [self upsideDownImageRepresenation]];

    upsideDownImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(upsideDownImageView.transform, 1, -1);

    UIView* container=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:upsideDownImageView.frame];
    [container addSubview:upsideDownImageView];
    UIImage* toReturn=nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(container.frame.size);

    [container.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    toReturn = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //[upsideDownImageView release];
    upsideDownImageView = nil;
    container = nil;
    //[container release];
    return toReturn;
}
```

---

---

```
-(UIImage*) upsideDownImageRepresenation
{
    int imageWidth = CGRectGetWidth([self bounds]);
    int imageHeight = CGRectGetHeight([self bounds]);

    //image buffer for export
    NSInteger myDataLength = imageWidth* imageHeight * 4;

    // allocate array and read pixels into it.
    GLubyte *tempImagebuffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);

    glReadPixels( 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tempImagebuffer);

    // make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, tempImagebuffer, myDataLength, ProviderReleaseData);

    // prep the ingredients
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;

   int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * imageWidth;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;

    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // make the cgimage
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(imageWidth, imageHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    // then make the uiimage from that
    UIImage *myImage =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef] ;

    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);

    return myImage;
}
```

Now you have a **UIImageView Representation of the UIView .**

> Now lets make this with the mask effect.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0); //imageView is wt we got by converting the UIIVew.
        [self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
// Add the mask Images even if want any UILabels etc ..
        [imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 703, 315)];
        [maskImages.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.2];
        [lblAckNo drawTextInRect:CGRectMake(320, 230,100,50)];

        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();// image with all of your effort.
        [[UIColor redColor] set];

         UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```