# Save UIView with CALayer.mask as UIImage in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage, calayer

I have the following code:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
}
else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainView.bounds.size);
}

[mainView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *saveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

In mainView, there is a masked subview that does not appear in saveImage when using this method. However, I understand there used to be a UIGetScreenImage method pre iOS 4 that did capture such activity. My question is, what is the best way to capture CALayer activities in iOS 6? Is UIGetScreenImage still private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there was a similar question about a week ago: [Mask does not work when capturing a uiview to a uiimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910742/mask-does-not-work-when-capturing-a-uiview-to-a-uiimage)

On iOS6 there is a problem capturing a UIView with the mask applied (btw, in iOS 7 it has been fixed): you capture the image but the mask is not applied.

I posted a lengthy solution which involved applying the mask manually to the captured image. It's not very difficult and I also made a demo project of this. You can download it here:

https://bitbucket.org/reydan/so_imagemask

If I did not understand your problem correctly, please tell me so I can remove this answer.

Comment: Yes you understood it properly. As a matter of fact I basically answered my own question by doing something like you did. I just manually created the masks using Core Graphics. Nonetheless, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Cool. Please note that this was fixed on iOS 7, when you do `renderInContext:` it will consider the mask applied to the layer and give you a good result. So, it would be wise to consider both versions since iOS7 will soon be available to the public.

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder how did you go about creating a mask with Core Graphics. I am trying to simulate CALayer mask behavior with Core Graphics and I am having no luck. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

try getting the presentation layer instead, as it will contain the layer's state.

```
[mainView.layer.presentationLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I already gave this a try. It was not successful.

Comment: You might need to create a composite drawing of all your layer than, and that will be slow as one call to `renderInContext` already is. UIGetScreenImage is private since iOS 4 or so. iOS 7 that's still under NDA has a new high performance way of doing that.